# Android Studio "Unknown attribute android:text" warning in new project

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-studio-3.5, android-xml-attribute

There's a warning that annoys me in Android Studio 3.5.3 for Linux, which I'm trying for the first time.
I'm following the Android Tutorial [Create an interactive Dice Roller app](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-app-with-button) and, on the 3rd step, it says that the button's text could be altered by changing the attribute "text" on the menu "Declared Attributes" in the layout editor.

Problem is: I don't have such attribute in the list.

Partial solution: I can change it in the activity xml. There's an attribute named android:text. Changing this attribute changes also the text in the design window, and there's no warning on building either.

Anyway on the xml file this warning is issued:

> Unknown attribute android:text
>
> Inspection info: This inspection highlights unknown XML attributes in Android resource
> files and AndroidManifest.xml

I can't find any solution for getting rid of it. I tried, without any luck, to emptying/invalidate caches (even if it's a new project), deleting everything inside AndroidStudio3.5/system/caches and gradle/caches, resyncing gradle, deleting .idea folder and eventually reinstalling Android Studio.

This applies also to other elements that have the same attribute like TextView, EditText or CheckBox. The attribute android:ems is also affected by this warning. It either case, it doesn't seem to cause problems on the designer or the builder, so I think I can just ignore the warning, but anyway I'd like to know why it's issued.

Unknown attribute android:text highlighted on activity_main.xml

[image]

edit: my Sdk Build-Tools version is 33 (it's the one that comes with the standard installation, I didn't change it)

Comment: what's your compileSdkVersion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're compileSdkVersion is 33,try downgrading it to 32 in build.gradle(:app)

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution!
The warning is no longer issued and "text" is among the "Declared attributes"!

Comment: I guess there is a bug with the 33

Answer (score 2):

The same goes here, as long as it's compiling we're fine

As already stated, due to: `compileSdkVersion 33`